# Parse Migration - No reachable servers on migration to mlab database

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, mlab

I have followed the migration steps on both the parse website as well as the mlab website and I am getting the No reachable servers error when trying to migrate the data from parse to mlab with my connection string.

Is there something I am missing or do I need to activate something on my mlab database?

Attached are screenshots from the Parse website. I have contacted them through their Facebook developer platform but have heard nothing since last night.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz949.png)

[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gC32J.png)

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with more detail (e.g. what your connection string looks like, excluding actual real credentials). Hard to tell what's going wrong without any concrete info. Nothing has to be "activated" on the mlab side though - it's just like any other mongodb database.

Comment: I have contacted mlab and their response is:
Thank you for your patience. This appears to be an issue with Parse.com.

Your deployment ds029436/the_brides_office is currently available on mLab.